# To create an empty dictionary, [NSMutableDictionary dictionary] or [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

To create an empty dictionary, should I call `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` or `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`?

What's the difference?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]` is the same as `[[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] autorelease]`

Comment: Thanks. For iPhone programming, I think [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init] is preferred.

Comment: @Stephen: ??? Why do you think that way? Sure, in many cases, you will probably be better off releasing things immediately after you're finished with them but you can also kill off an autorelease pool after every n cycles in a tight loop to manage memory usage as well. As you stated it, however, your comment is too general to be true.

Answer (score 13):

for the sake of completeness, some years later we got other shorter way to alloc Dictionary:

```
NSMutableDictionary* dictionary = @{}.mutableCopy;
```

Comment: The docs says "Returns a new instance that’s a mutable copy of the receiver." what if I just use @{} ?

Answer (score 7):

The difference is that if you use  `NSMutableDictionary* myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`  you will have to later call  `[myDictionary release]`  when you're done with it. Otherwise you will leak memory. If you use the other method you don't have to worry about memory management.

Comment: You still have to worry about memory management with autoreleased instances. Consider e.g. creating many arrays in a tight loop without draining the corresponding autorelease pool.

Answer (score 2):

With ARC, there is no difference between all three options:

1. `@{}.mutableCopy`
2. `[NSMutableDictionary dictionary]`
3. `[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]`

Only the first and second can be justified based on shortness or readability.